# Excel: XML - ContextMenu editing for ContextMenuListRange

Tags: xml, vba, excel, contextmenu

I am trying to hide elements of the `<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuListRange">` for Excel. My problem is that I cannot find the child `idMso`'s anywhere. (Not even in Office UI Help Files).

I've resorted to guessing and this is getting me nowhere. Anyone know where I can find this info? Most helpful would be seeing the `XML` that drives this context menu.

[image: img]

My guesses so far:

```
<contextMenus>
   <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuListRange">
    <button visible = "false" idMso = "Cut"/>
    <button visible = "false" idMso = "Copy"/>
    <button visible = "false" idMso = "InsertComment"/> <!--Not correct-->
    <button visible = "false" idMso = "FormatCells"/> <!--Not correct-->
    <button visible = "false" idMso = "Hyperlink"/> <!--Not correct-->
   </contextMenu>
</contextMenus>
```

Comment: So basically you're looking for the three "note correct" element names shown in your example xml, correct?

Comment: Not just those three, but all the child elements of the context menu. Those three were just an example of how I've been trying to guess at their idMso.

Comment: This is REALLY close to what I'm looking for: [link](http://www.ribboncreator2010.de/Onlinehelp/EN/_2hm0n7htf.htm). I'm just missing those sub-menus like "Insert", "Delete", "Select"

Comment: Which version of Excel are you running? (Some item names have slight differences depending on version.)

Comment: Excel from Office 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance I thought I'd have a list of `idMSO`'s in no time, but it ended up not being that simple.

Documentation is limited  for manual RibbonX design -- since Microsoft's recommended (and [supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608616.aspx)) method is with Visual Studio 2017 (which [free](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/?utm_source=web&utm_medium=documentation&utm_campaign=vs2017upgrade&utm_term=vs2017) for individual developers).

Beyond that, your best best may be to stick with **VBA**.

If you haven't tried it, there's also:

> ***ContextMenus Add-In for Office 2010***
>   A com add-in from Microsoft adds `idMso` name to the bottom of every Context menu. A simple way to determine the `idMso` for use it in the RibbonX. (Requires `.NET Framework` version 3.5)
>
> - Download Microsoft ContextMenusaddin from Ron de Bruin's site [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winfiles/contextmenusaddin.zip).
> - More info including Downloadable Dynamic menu Example files [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win014.htm).
>
> I couldn't get it working since it's specific to 2010 but it sounds promising.

Beyond that, your best best may be to stick with **VBA**.

I slapped together an Excel function to list all ~1600 controls from 174 commands bar - but it could be easily adapted to modify the toolbars as well.

For example this statement disables the `Insert Comments` command on the context menu:  <sub>(and `=TRUE` to re-enable)</sub>

```
Application.CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(ID:=2031).Enabled = False
```

...and an example of `get`ting the value of a property:

```
Debug.Print Application.CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(ID:=2031).Caption
```

...or, same result, but using CallByName so the property names can come from variables (or parsed directly):

```
Debug.Print CallByName(Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls(cIndex), "Caption", VbGet)
```

**`CommandBarControls`** don't have a ***`Name`*** per se (They have `Captions`, `accDescription`, `TooltipText`, and `accName` etc., but no regular `Name` like it's `Commandbar` parents do) so the best way to refer to them is by the `ID`.

---

### Sample Output:

```
   Index      Id   accState   Caption                       Enabled
       1      21    1048576   Cu&t                           TRUE
       2      19    1048576   &Copy                          TRUE
       3      22          1   &Paste                         FALSE
       4   21437          1   Paste &Special...              FALSE
       5    3624          1   &Paste Table                   FALSE
       6   25536    1048576   Smart &Lookup                  TRUE
       7   32736      32768   Tran&slate                     TRUE
       8   32713      32768   &Linked Entity                 TRUE
       9    3181    1048576   &Insert...                     TRUE
      10    3181      32768   &Insert...                     TRUE
      11     292    1048576   &Delete...                     TRUE
      12    3125    1048576   Clear Co&ntents                TRUE
      13   24508    1048576   &Quick Analysis                TRUE
      14   31623      32768   Sp&arklines                    TRUE
      15   31402    1048576   Filt&er                        TRUE
      16   31435    1048576   S&ort                          TRUE
      17    2031    1048576   Insert Co&mment                TRUE
      18    1592      32769   Delete Co&mment                FALSE
      19    1593      32769   Sh&ow/Hide Comments            FALSE
      20     855    1048576   &Format Cells...               TRUE
      21    1966    1048576   Pic&k From Drop-down List...   TRUE
      22    1614      32768   &Show Phonetic Field           TRUE
      23   13380    1048576   Define N&ame...                TRUE
      24    1576      32768   &Hyperlink...                  TRUE
      25    1577      32769   Edit &Hyperlink...             FALSE
      26    1015      32769   &Open Hyperlink                FALSE
      27    3626      32769   &Remove Hyperlink              FALSE
```

The errors you mentioned are because every `CommandBar` doesn't necessarily have every `Property` - but a `Resume Next` takes care of that.  Since each version of Excel has slight `CommandBar` differences, it would be best to generate the list on your machine to account for differences  between our versions.

```
Option Explicit

Sub listContextMenuCommands()

    Const wkshtName = "Commands2"
    Const startRow = 1
    Dim commandbarIndex As Integer
    Dim cIndex As Integer, sht As Worksheet, cb As CommandBar
    Dim cellCmd As Variant, testVar As Variant
    Dim col As Integer, rw As Integer

    'list of selected properties to report upon
    cellCmd = Array("accChild", "accChildCount", "accDefaultAction", "accDescription", "accDoDefaultAction", _
        "accFocus", "accHelp", "accHelpTopic", "accHitTest", "accKeyboardShortcut", "accLocation", "accName", _
        "accNavigate", "accParent", "accRole", "accSelect", "accSelection", "accState", "accValue", "AdaptiveMenu", _
        "AddRef", "BeginGroup", "BuiltIn", "Caption", "Context", "Controls", "Creator", "DescriptionText", _
        "Enabled", "GetIDsOfNames", "GetTypeInfo", "GetTypeInfoCount", "Height", "HelpContextID", "Id", "Index", _
        "InstanceId", "InstanceIdPtr)", "Invoke", "IsPriorityDropped", "Left", "Name", "NameLocal", "OLEUsage", _
        "OnAction", "Parameter", "Parent", "Position", "Priority", "Protection", "QueryInterface", "Release", _
        "RowIndex", "Tag", "TooltipText", "Top", "Type", "Visible", "Width")

    'prepare worksheet for output
    Set sht = Sheets(wkshtName)
    rw = startRow
    If MsgBox("Existing data will be cleared from worksheet '" & wkshtName & "'.", vbOKCancel, "Erase data?") <> vbOK Then Exit Sub
    sht.Cells.ClearContents 'delete all values
    sht.Activate

    'populate headings
    sht.Cells(rw, 1) = "CommandBar"
    sht.Range(Cells(rw, 2), Cells(rw, UBound(cellCmd) + 1)) = cellCmd 'dump array of headings into range
    On Error Resume Next 'errors will be generated for properties unavailable for certain commands

    For commandbarIndex = 1 To Application.CommandBars.Count 'enumerate all command bars

        Set cb = Application.CommandBars(commandbarIndex) ' refer to commandbar by name (like "Cell"=context menu) or by Index #
        For cIndex = 1 To cb.Controls.Count ' enumerate all controls on commandbar
            testVar = CallByName(cb.Controls(cIndex), "Index", VbGet)
            If Err Then 'error: control doesn't exist
                Debug.Print "No cIndex : Commandbar: #" & cb.Index & " '" & cb.Name & "' Ctl# " & cIndex
                Err.Clear 'clear error
                GoTo nextCtl 'skip this command
            End If

            rw = rw + 1 'next row
            sht.Cells(rw, 1) = cb.Name 'title of command bar in first column

            For col = 1 To UBound(cellCmd) 'populate each [col] for this [rw]
                'use "CallByName" so we can specify control name with variables (array)
                sht.Cells(rw, col + 1) = CallByName(cb.Controls(cIndex), cellCmd(col - 1), VbGet)
                If Err Then 'catch error
                    sht.Cells(rw, col + 1) = "{N/A}" 'property not available for this control
                    Err.Clear 'clear error
                End If

            Next col 'next column
            Application.StatusBar = "Listing Commands: " & Format(commandbarIndex / Application.CommandBars.Count, "0.0%")

nextCtl:
        Next cIndex  'next control
        DoEvents
    Next commandbarIndex 'next commandbar

    sht.[a1].Select
    sht.Columns.AutoFit

    Debug.Print "Finished " & Application.CommandBars.Count & " Command Bars, " & rw - startRow & " commands."
End Sub
```

The code's a little messy an inefficient so it might hang for a moment while it grabs the ~100k properties.  You just need to specify a blank worksheet name in the constant, but then you'll hopefully have a complete list of relevant command bar info.

---

### More Info from MSDN:

- [CommandBar Properties (Office)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/commandbar-properties-office)
- [CommandBars Members (Office)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Office-Shared-VBA/articles/commandbars-members-office)
- [Customizing Context Menus in All Versions of Microsoft Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469862(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2/3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199.aspx)
- [CommandBars.FindControl Method (Office)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/commandbars-findcontrol-method-office)
- [CallByName Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/callbyname-function)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some VBA code to iterate through the list of controls and output their names (menu text) and IDs.  From here you could iterate through the controls and enable / disable by name or ID.

```
' Delete the custom controls with the Tag : My_Cell_Control_Tag.
    For Each ctrl In ContextMenu.Controls
        If ctrl.Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag" Then
            ctrl.Delete
        End If
    Next ctrl
```

Full code to List out each Control, you could do something in the loop to delete every control except what you want to keep.

```
Sub ControlList()
  Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar
  Dim ctrl As CommandBarControl

  ' Set ContextMenu to the Cell context menu.
  Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")

  Set xmlControl = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  xmlControl.LoadXML ("<xml/>")



  For Each ctrl In ContextMenu.Controls
    Set ndChild = xmlControl.createNode(1, "control", "")
    ' Call ndChild.setAttribute("tooltip", ctrl.TooltipText)
    Call ndChild.setAttribute("caption", ctrl.Caption)
    Call ndChild.setAttribute("visible", ctrl.Visible)
    Call ndChild.setAttribute("id", ctrl.ID)
    Set ndChild = xmlControl.DocumentElement.appendChild(ndChild)
  Next ctrl
  ' xmlControl.Save ("c:\temp\controllist.xml")
  MsgBox xmlControl.xml
End Sub

<xml>
  <control caption="Cu&amp;t" visible="-1" id="21" />
  <control caption="&amp;Copy" visible="-1" id="19" />
  <control caption="&amp;Paste" visible="-1" id="22" />
  <control caption="Paste &amp;Special..." visible="-1" id="21437" />
  <control caption="&amp;Paste Table" visible="-1" id="3624" />
  <control caption="&amp;Insert..." visible="-1" id="3181" />
  <control caption="&amp;Delete..." visible="-1" id="292" />
  <control caption="Clear Co&amp;ntents" visible="-1" id="3125" />
  <control caption="Sp&amp;arklines" visible="0" id="31623" />
  <control caption="Filt&amp;er" visible="-1" id="31402" />
  <control caption="S&amp;ort" visible="-1" id="31435" />
  <control caption="Insert Co&amp;mment" visible="-1" id="2031" />
  <control caption="Delete Co&amp;mment" visible="0" id="1592" />
  <control caption="Sh&amp;ow/Hide Comments" visible="0" id="1593" />
  <control caption="&amp;Format Cells..." visible="-1" id="855" />
  <control caption="Pic&amp;k From Drop-down List..." visible="-1" id="1966" />
  <control caption="&amp;Show Phonetic Field" visible="0" id="1614" />
  <control caption="Define N&amp;ame..." visible="-1" id="13380" />
  <control caption="&amp;Hyperlink..." visible="-1" id="1576" />
  <control caption="Edit &amp;Hyperlink..." visible="0" id="1577" />
  <control caption="&amp;Open Hyperlink" visible="0" id="1015" />
  <control caption="&amp;Remove Hyperlink" visible="0" id="3626" />
  <control caption="E&amp;xpand to detail" visible="0" id="11299" />
  <control caption="Additional Act&amp;ions" visible="0" id="31595" />
  <control caption="F&amp;ull Screen" visible="0" id="178" />
  <control caption="&amp;Additional Actions" visible="-1" id="22577" />
</xml>
```

Comment: So, this is kind of the path I had started down initially. The problem is that the caption and id are not valid attributes in the xml representation. When I tried this, I get all kinds of xml errors like "The id attribute is not allowed " and "The caption attribute is not declared". It seems that for built in controls, you have to reference the idMso attribute to get to them in xml. :-(

Comment: I see what you mean.  Looking at MSDN, you can iterate through all the captions, and delete what you need.  Have a look at the delete function code I got from the MSDN site.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task you should use [RibbonX Visual Designer](http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor.htm).

You can have a look at [this](https://books.google.it/books?id=6ftcCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA616&lpg=PA618#v=onepage&q&f=false) chapter of the "**Excel 2016 Power Programming with VBA**" book to get few more informations.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The RibbonX Visual Designer is really neat, but it will not meet my needs here as it does not have a designer section for context menus (right click menus).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for the Insert Comment control:

```
Application.CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(ID:=2031).Enabled = False
```

Alistair Mcmillan has code at [this blog](https://alistairmcmillan.github.io/2016/03/29/List-Excel-command-bars-and-controls.html) post that will get you the complete list of IDs you need for your commands. I'm linking to it but not reposting because it's not mine to post.